# Sorting generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have to implement a generic AVL tree as homework. It's defined as follows:

```
public class AVL<Key,Elem>;
```

The problem is that I assume that at some point, I'll have to compare keys to decide in which side of a node I allocate an element. For the purpose of this homework, Integers will be used as Keys.

Since no other restriction or information about that is given, I first thought of just asuming that Key will always be an Integer. However, that makes the generic "Key" superfluous, and I don't think that's what the teachers expect. So, I think that the best solution involves forcing that whatever that is passed as Key implements a Comparator, or something like that (I've really never worked with Comparator, just guessing), and then using that comparator to compare the Keys instead of using the ==,<,> and != operators. However, I have no idea on how to do it. Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `public class AVL<Key extends Comparable<Key>,Elem>;` and use the `compareTo()` method which is required by the `Comparable<T>` interface and which is implemented by `Integer`.

Comment: What's the difference between this solution and using Comparator? Someone told me he made it using it. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I think you mix `Comparable` up with `Comparator`. The comparator would be an object that compares any type of object without the need to implement `Comparable`. However, your key would not implement `Comparator` but you'd pass it as a separate object. On the other hand `Comparable` marks an object as having a natural order (defined by the implementation of `comparaTo()` and if your keys implemented it they could be compared directly. Note that all `Number` objects (`Integer`, `Double` etc.) as well as  `String` implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Got it. Gonna start reading the Java documentation about the Comparable interface. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `SortedMap` and `SortedSet` implementations in the standard Java API either use a `Comparator<Key>` and call its `compare(k1, k2)` method, or assume the keys implement `Comparable<Key>`, and call `k1.compareTo(k2)`. Most offer both, depending on which constructor is used. (EnumMap/EnumSet don't, as they support only the build-in ordering of the enum values by declaration order.)

The `Comparable` approach mandates that the keys are always sorted in the same way, and would be used for keys which have a canonical ordering (like integers), where you want to use this ordering.

The `Comparator` approach is more flexible, since you can use the same key objects for different maps where they are differently ordered, and you can use it for keys over which you have no control, or who don't have a canonical ordering (like List, trees/graphs, etc. You can also use it to sort strings keys by other criteria than the pure unicode value (e.g. Locale-based), using a Collator (this is a class implementing Comparator).

Both require a total order on your keys, but I suppose this is necessary for your AVL tree, too.

Here is a Comparator implementation which works on any comparable objects, so you could use it (maybe internally) as an adapter for the Comparable variant.

```
 public static <X extends Comparable<X>> Comparator<X> makeComparator() {
     return new Comparator<X>() {
         public int compare(X left, X right) {
             return left.compareTo(right);
         }
     };
 }
```

Comment: In fact, my Main class will need to sort items by different criteria, and I will need to instance various AVLs for each kind of sorting, working with the best one for every case. I guess this can be done by using a different field of the object as Key every time and the Comparable interface, or by removing the generic "Key" and passing a different comparator every time which compares the desired field every time, but since they gave us the signature with the generic "Key", they want to force us to use the first method. Isn't it?

Comment: You seem to have the special case that the key is part of the value, which you extract. In this case, both approaches are usable. You could alternatively implement `SortedSet<Value>` and use a suitable Comparator (but if the task want `<Key, Value>`, use both). It does not really matter, the underlying mechanism is nearly the same.